# How to keep one jQuery UI's draggable group above the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 classes of divs to which I apply draggable with the stack option set.

How can I make one of those classes(class "A") float above the other one(class "B"), so that no matter if the object is moved in the B all the elements in A stay above all of the elements in B?

CSS:

```
div { opacity:0.5; position:absolute; font-size:2em; padding:20px; }

.above { background:green; }
.below { background:red; }
```

JS:

```
$("div").draggable({ stack:'div' });
```

​
HTML:

```
<div class="above" style="left:30px; top:0px">A1</div>
<div class="above" style="left:60px; top:0px">A2</div>
<div class="above" style="left:90px; top:0px">A3</div>

<div class="below" style="left:30px; top:30px">B1</div>
<div class="below" style="left:60px; top:30px">B2</div>
<div class="below" style="left:90px; top:30px">B3</div>​
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Cje9/2/

Comment: Do you have some code we can take a look at? It's easier for us to help you if you provide a coded example :) www.jsfiddle.net is a great resource for this.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for the suggestion, here's the link: bit.ly/UpQTpZ

Comment: -1, put your code inline.  Do not just stick it in a jsfiddle, and absolutely do not use a URL shortener to get around the content filter.

Comment: @user1933711, I've done your work for you.  Please follow this example if you have the chance to ask further questions.  Note how posting a link to a jsfiddle *works* when you include code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example:

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navi">a</div>
    <div id="infoi"><img src="info_icon2.png" height="20" width="32"/>b</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#navi, 
#infoi {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#infoi {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Add these styles to two respective divs.it'll solve your problem.
I would suggest learning about `position: relative` and child elements with `position: absolute`.